# JSONDecodeError Exception Value: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm working on a Django app and I'm trying to redirect based on a response from an API, but I can't seem to find a way to get the value of the response.

This is the response:

```
{
"Body": {
    "stkCallback": {
        "MerchantRequestID": "24915-30681242-1",
        "CheckoutRequestID": "ws_CO_150220211305438433",
        "ResultCode": 0,
        "ResultDesc": "The service request is processed successfully.",
        "CallbackMetadata": {
            "Item": [
                {
                    "Name": "Amount",
                    "Value": 1.00
                },
                {
                    "Name": "MpesaReceiptNumber",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Name": "TransactionDate",
                    "Value": 20210215130604
                },
                {
                    "Name": "PhoneNumber",
                    "Value": 
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Found a way to get the request but instead of returning as `dict` it returns a `str` even though i used `json.loads()`.

getting `result_code`  throws an error `string indices must be integers`

```
def callback(request):

    callback = json.dumps(request.body.decode('utf-8'))

    body_data = json.loads(callback)

    print(type(body_data)) #returns 'str'

    result_code = body_data["Body"]["stkCallback"]["ResultCode"]

    print(result_code)  #returns string indices must be integers

return render(request, 'callback.html')
```

Comment: Please share your full traceback.

Comment: Ensure you are getting JSON returned from API call, also this response is not valid JSON

Comment: How do i convert it to JSON with python?

Comment: @JosphatGitogo- Depends on the datatype you are receiving. Check the datatype that is being sent by the API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@josphat Gitogo - Shouldn't it be `resultcode = response['Body']['stkCallback']['ResultCode']`

```
try:
    response = json.loads(request.body).decode('utf-8')
    resultcode = response['Body']['stkCallback']['ResultCode']
except ValueError as v:  # includes simplejson.decoder.JSONDecodeError
   #log the exception or print it
```

Assuming response =

```
{
"Body": {
    "stkCallback": {
        "MerchantRequestID": "24915-30681242-1",
        "CheckoutRequestID": "ws_CO_150220211305438433",
        "ResultCode": 0,
        "ResultDesc": "The service request is processed successfully.",
        "CallbackMetadata": {
            "Item": [
                {
                    "Name": "Amount",
                    "Value": 1.00
                },
                {
                    "Name": "MpesaReceiptNumber",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Name": "TransactionDate",
                    "Value": 20210215130604
                },
                {
                    "Name": "PhoneNumber",
                    "Value":
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
}
```

Also, I see one of your Value attribute has no value.

```
 {
                    "Name": "PhoneNumber",
                    "Value":
                }
```

Comment: Tried your solution but it still throws this error. `JSONDecodeError at /api/v1/online/lipa/callback/`

Comment: `Exception Type: JSONDecodeError
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`